# Figure out different values to send partial update to server

Tags: ramda.js

From a form submission I receive two objects: the original values and the dirty values. I like to figure out how to create a diff to send to the server using the following rules:

1. id field of the root object should always be included
2. all changed primitive values should be included
3. all nested changes should be included as well.
4. if a nested value other than id changed, it should include id as well.

Original values:

```
{ 
    "id":10,
    "name": "tkvw"
    "locale": "nl",
    "address":{
        "id":2,
        "street": "Somewhere",
        "zipcode": "8965",
    },
    "subscriptions":[8,9,10],
    "category":{
       "id":6
    },    
}
```

Example expected diff objects:

1) User changes field `name` to "Foo"

```
{
    "id":10,
    "name":"foo"
}
```

2) User changes field `street` on address node and `category`

```
{
    "id":10,
    "address":{
        "id": 2,
        "street":"Changed"
    },
    "category":{
        "id":5
    }
}
```

I do understand the basics of functional programming, but I just need a hint in the right direction (some meta code maybe).

Comment: I can't tell if (1) and (2) are example outputs of your desired function or inputs to it.  If they're outputs, what is the input?  If they're input, what's the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSON Patch (rfc6902)](http://jsonpatch.com), JSON Patch is a format for describing changes to a JSON document. For example:

```
[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/baz", "value": "boo" },
  { "op": "add", "path": "/hello", "value": ["world"] },
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/foo"}
]
```

You generate a patch by comparing to JS objects/arrays, and then you can apply the patch to the original object (on the server side for example) to reflect changes.

You can create a patch using the [fast-json-patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-json-patch) lib.

```js
const obj1 = {"id":10,"name":"tkvw","locale":"nl","address":{"id":2,"street":"Somewhere","zipcode":"8965"},"subscriptions":[8,9,10],"category":{"id":6}};

const obj2 = {"id":10,"name":"cats","locale":"nl","address":{"id":2,"street":"Somewhere","zipcode":"8965"},"subscriptions":[8,9,10,11],"category":{"id":7}};

const delta = jsonpatch.compare(obj1, obj2);

console.log('delta:\n', delta);

const doc = jsonpatch.applyPatch(obj1, delta).newDocument;

console.log('patched obj1:\n', doc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fast-json-patch/2.0.6/fast-json-patch.min.js"></script>
```